# Install MySql With default Configure automatically

Tags: mysql, installation

I created a java application with mysql,hibernate.
I building a installer for my application and want to install mysql With default Configure  on user PC automatically.
how to install mysql automatically without be user set Configure(example password,user,instance)?
On Windows and linux

Comment: On which environment?  Linux?  Mac?  Windows?  PalmOS?  Additionally, this is more of a serverfault question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL installer for windows](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/) installs it automatically with default settings...

Answer (score 1):

Installing on Ubuntu is as straight forward as:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Answer (score 0):

For automatic install all components and configure it in a Windows you can use program 
**MYSQL_INSTALL_AUTOMATIC_ALL_COMPONENT_AND_CONFIGURE_IT.exe** . It is describe 
on my GitHub repository [Install-automatic-MYSQL-all-component-and-configure](https://github.com/sp9auv/Install-automatic-MYSQL-all-component-and-configure)

The program is used for automatic and very easy install MYSQL database and do its configuration automatically so that the user does not have to choose any parameter from the menu or need read help . Almost all operation is hidden . Only must only approve a few (3-4) button's type NEXT. All parameters are stored in the **config file setup.ini** what can be edit and change by programmer to adapt it , according to the needs .
There are also **source in Delphi** .
[Click there to see example screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5KPR.jpg)